# Prove $3(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)\ge xyz(x+y+z)^3$

Tags: inequality

> if $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers,Prove:$$3(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)\ge xyz(x+y+z)^3$$
>
> Additional info:$\sum_{cyc}$ denotes sums over cyclic permutations of the symbols $x,y,z$. I'm looking for solutions and hint that using Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM because I have background in them.

*Things I have done:* Writing Left hand side in expanded form:$$LHS=3(\sum_{cyc}x^3y^3+\sum_{cyc}xy^4z+3x^2y^2z^2)$$

Right now I don't have good idea were to start(Is expanding and looking for AM-GM is good?).So any hint is appreciated.

*Source :* This inequality can be found as Problem 42, page 13, in the book "Old and New inequalities" by Titu Andreescu, where it is attributed to Manlio Marangelli.

Comment: For $x=y=z$ the inequality states $27x^6 \geq 9x^5$ which certainly is not true for all $x>0$.

Comment: It's likely $(x+y+z)^3$ on LHS.

Comment: @user133281,you are right.Maybe there is a missing assumption.like $x+y+z=1$?

Comment: Or equivalently, what Quang Hoang said.

Comment: I edited it as @QuangHoang suggested it maybe the correct form.

Comment: So you actually are not sure what the correct form is?

Comment: @user133281,Well,the book that is in my hand had couple of mistyping, so it could be just another of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to

$$3\sum x^3y^3 +2\sum xy^4z+3x^2y^2z^2\ge 3\sum(xy^3z^2+x^2y^3z) =3\sum xy^3z(x+z)$$

AM-GM gives

$$x^3y^3+xy^4z+x^2y^2z^2\ge 3 x^2y^3z$$
$$y^3z^3+xy^4z+x^2y^2z^2\ge 3xy^3z^2$$
Summing up we have
$$2\sum x^3y^3+2\sum xy^4z+6x^2y^2z^2\ge 3\sum (x^2y^3z+xy^3z^2),$$
or 
$$\sum x^3y^3+\sum xy^4z+3x^2y^2z^2\ge \frac32\sum(x^2y^3z+xy^3z^2).\tag{1}$$
Now, note that 
$$x^3+y^3\ge xy^2+yx^2.\tag{2}$$
Multiplying (2) with $xyz$ gives
$$\sum xy^4z\ge \frac12\sum(x^2y^3z+x^3y^2z)\tag{3}.$$
Multiplying (2) with $z^3$ gives
$$\sum (x^3z^3+y^3z^3)\ge \sum(xy^2z^3+x^2yz^3).\tag{4}$$
The inequality follows from (1), (3), and (4).

**Note**: It may not be a good book to work with after all. And I'm sure there are other non brute-force proofs.

Comment: thanks for posting your solution.and about the book I agree with you.but I should solve it questions anyway.could you recommend any good books about inequalities?I have Cauchy-Schwartz master class,Algebraic inequalities and  Inequalities Theorems,Techniques and Selected Problems

Comment: I recommend Pham Kim Hung's Secret's in inequalities, volumes 1-2. (Haven't found the time so far to read them completely.) It explains common techniques with a lot of examples and challenging problems.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to expand your list of basic inequalities, by Holder's inequality
$$LHS=(1+1+1)(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)(zx^2+xy^2+yz^2) \ge \left(\sqrt[3]{x^4yz}+\sqrt[3]{xy^4z}+\sqrt[3]{xyz^4}\right)^3=RHS$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\let\geq\geqslant\let\leq\leqslant$the inequality is homogenous, we may assume $x+y+z=1$. The inequality can be rewritten as
$$3\cdot\sum_{cyc}\frac xy\sum_{cyc}\frac yx\geq\frac1{xyz}.$$
By weighted AM-GM,
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac xy\geq(x+y+z)\sqrt[x+y+z]{\frac1{y^xx^zz^y}}.$$
Combining a similar inequality for the other factor yields 
$$LHS\geq3\frac{x^xy^yz^z}{xyz},$$
so it suffices to prove $3x^xy^yz^z\geq1$, which is true by Jensen's inequality in the form
$$x\log x+y\log y+z\log z\geq3\frac{x+y+z}3\log\frac{x+y+z}3=-\log 3$$
because $x\log x$ is convex on the interval $]0,1]$.

Comment: Surely weighted AM-GM _plus_ Jensen is an overkill for this, but it's only meant to illustrate a beautiful alternative.